# php redirect from https to http does not work

Tags: php, http, redirect, https, nginx

I have the following issue:

environment:

nginx web server running php-fpm, php 5.3.

when I try to force user leave https area, it redirect to https page again, which create infinity loop.

Test file:

```
header('Location: http://www.domain.com/phpinfo.php'); 
exit;
```

but it redirects to `**https**://www.domain.com/phpinfo.php` instead.

Any ideas? nginx\php setup is pretty common. No general http->https redirects in nginx config file.

**Update**

1. Browser cache is excluded, I'm using anonymous mode each time to test.
2. Redirects are "moved temporary".

Any ides?

Thanks

Comment: Did you maybe redirect to the secure area with a 301 (Moved Permanently) status code? You should be using (probably) 302 and 303 redirects, maybe the occasional 307.

Comment: Redirections can be cached in browsers. Rule out it is not that by running your url through something like http://redbot.org/ to see if it is still doing the redirection.

Comment: @AnthonyHatzopoulos `Redirections can be cached in browsers.` - Only 301's should be "cached". Everything else should generate a new request every time.

Comment: @DaveRandom `Only 301's should be "cached"` Not true and it depends what browser is handling the redirect, http://www.stevesouders.com/blog/2010/07/23/redirect-caching-deep-dive/

Comment: @AnthonyHatzopoulos They key work there is *should*. But nice link, thanks for that, and it's definitely true that in the world of web browsers RFCs are often basically treated as optional.

Comment: Is there anything else in your environment that can redirect the user to https, such as an .htaccess file?

Comment: 1. Browser cache of requests is excluded (start anonymous mode each time)

Comment: can you alter your nginx config and set the error_log directive with debug level logging? it'll be nice to see a trace of what's going on